# How come I can't get audio in Chromium for WebVR?

Tags: aframe, webvr

I'm using Chromium for my Vive but don't get audio.

Console says: `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Unable to decode audio data`. Anyone had this issue already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using an open codec since Chromium is fully open. This means MP3s won't work in Chromium. Try converting your audio files to `.ogg`:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp3 out.ogg
```